# How to get event name in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

Here there are two handlers in a particular procedure then how to get which event handler has performed.

for example

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Events(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)     Handles TextBox1.TextChanged, TextBox1.GotFocus

End Sub
```

how to get which event has occured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible using the StackTrace (could be a better way I'm not sure...).  Try the following code.

```
 Private Sub TextBox1_Events(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged, TextBox1.GotFocus

        Dim s As New StackTrace(True)

        For Each f As StackFrame In s.GetFrames
            Debug.WriteLine(f.GetMethod.Name)
        Next

    End Sub
```

When the text box gets focus the following is written:

> TextBox1_Events
>
> OnGotFocus
>
> OnGotFocus
>
> WmSetFocus
>
> Ect…….

Where as when it’s a text changed event

> TextBox1_Events
>
> OnTextChanged
>
> OnTextChanged
>
> Ect….

I’m sure you could write something using this to do what you need.  But i fully agree with the other guys separate handlers is better.

Comment: If you're looking for weird hacky ways to handle it (having code know/depend on the specific code calling it is *definitely* a hack.  It severely hurts maintainability of the code), then a better way would be to create two separate handlers, and have them redirect to a single handler that accepts extra data, including the name of the original handler.  This is equivalent to splitting up the handlers, but at least it is strongly typed and doesn't (as strongly) increase the coupling of your code.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you cannot.

- If the events were bound to two separate controls, you could check the `sender` property for the type
- If the `e` argument for the event had some type other than `EventArgs` (some events use a different arguments type), or the control passed some type *derived* from `EventArgs`, then you might be able to check properties on that variable

There aren't any other tricks you could use because events don't provide any sort of data to the handler specifying *which* event occurred.

With these two events, they're both going to be sent from the same text box, so the first option is out.  Also, with both events, they send *just* an instance of the `EventArgs` class (not a derived class), so that option is out.

Ultimately, you're going to have to have multiple event handlers to solve this specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. If you're in a situation where you need to know which event occurred, you will always be better off using two separate handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with 2 events (similar in signature) emitted by the same control the easiest/cleanest way of solving this would be 2 separate event handlers (as suggested by Merlyn Morgan-Graham):

```
    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)     Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        'the TextChanged specific code would go here
        HandletTextBox1EventInternal(sender, e)
    End Sub 

    Private Sub TextBox1_GotFocus(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)     Handles TextBox1.GotFocus
        'the GotFocus specific code would go here
        HandletTextBox1EventInternal(sender, e)
    End Sub

    Private Sub HandleTextBox1EventInternal(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
            'code common to GotFocus and TextChanged handlers
    End sub
```

Comment: +1.  And also suggested by minitech.  Also, if you really wanted to have all the code that handles the call in the same handler, there's no reason that the `HandletTextBox1EventInternal` method couldn't accept an extra parameter specifying which handler called it.  `Sub HandleTextBox1EventInternal(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs, ByVal parentHandler As System.String)`.  This would basically match my comment under Rene147's answer.