# Two Type of event-handling Enter and Leave for textBox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, events, handler, enter

I am Using two types of event-handling `Enter` and `Leave` in one Function, using with `If-Statement`.

Anybody, please, correct my script.

```
Private Sub MaskedTextBox_Enter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OrgNameTextBox.Enter, OrgNameTextBox.Leave        
    If Event = Enter Then
        CType(sender, Control).BackColor = Color.Yellow
        CType(sender, Control).ForeColor = Color.Black

    ElseIf  Event = Leave Then
        CType(sender, Control).BackColor = Color.Black
        CType(sender, Control).ForeColor = Color.White

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: And what is the issue you are facing? Any error or output is not expected? Or some other issue?

Comment: @PM. `If Event = Enter Then` and ` ElseIf  Event = Leave Then` are dummy lines.
its example of what want i am... please correct this lines in correct format.

Comment: Hyi @PM Please Cleare My Question.
If TextBox.Enter Then `do Some Thing`  Elseif Textbox.Leave Then `do Some Thing2`. in One Function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you should have two separate handlers for two separate events because you are doing different things on different events. But if you must have only one handler then you can try something like, and I am pretty sure this is a HACK:

```
Private Sub MaskedTextBox_Enter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OrgNameTextBox.Enter, OrgNameTextBox.Leave
 Dim stackTrace As New StackTrace(True)
 Dim frame As StackFrame = stackTrace.GetFrames[0]
 If(frame.GetMethod.Name = 'OnEntered') <CHECK THE EVENT NAME, THIS IS JUST AN EXAMPLE>
            CType(sender, Control).BackColor = Color.Yellow
            CType(sender, Control).ForeColor = Color.Black
 End If
 If(frame.GetMethod.Name = 'OnLeave')        
            CType(sender, Control).BackColor = Color.Black
            CType(sender, Control).ForeColor = Color.White
 End If
End Sub
```

I had seen the way to get the event name somewhere in StackOverflow only, I will update the answer once I find it to give the correct credit :)

**EDITED ANSWER**

```
Private Sub MaskedTextBox_Enter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OrgNameTextBox.Enter, OrgNameTextBox.Leave
     Dim stackTrace As New StackTrace(True)
     For Each frame As StackFrame In s.GetFrames
      IF(frame.GetMethod.Name = 'OnEntered') <CHECK THE EVENT NAME, THIS IS JUST AN EXAMPLE>
                CType(sender, Control).BackColor = Color.Yellow
                CType(sender, Control).ForeColor = Color.Black
      End IF
      IF(frame.GetMethod.Name = 'OnLeave')        
                CType(sender, Control).BackColor = Color.Black
                CType(sender, Control).ForeColor = Color.White
      End If
   NEXT --THIS NEEDS TO BE CHECKED, YOU MAY WANT TO EXIT BEFORE,ONCE FOUND YOUR EVENT.
 End Sub
```

Also found the actual answer mentioned earlier for credit. It's [How to get event name in vb.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092367/how-to-get-event-name-in-vb-net)

Comment: `stackTrace.GetFrames[0]` Red Marking is `Value of type StackFrame cannot be convert to StackFrame`

Comment: Check now, this may help.

Comment: Thanks Dear its Working Good.